# How to differentiate "+" between adding and concatenating

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="inputbox"></br>
    <input type="button" value="Convert" onclick="kelvinCelsius();">
    </form>

    <div id="answer"></div>

    <script>
        function kelvinCelsius(){
         var theanswer = inputbox.value + 237.15
         answer.innerHTML = theanswer
        }
    </script>
```

I input 3 into the form and instead of getting 240.15, I get 3237.15. How can I make it so it adds the two values instead of concatenating them?

Comment: `parseInt(inputbox.value)` and also add `;` at the end of your commands.

Comment: This must be a duplicate from very long ago…

Comment: @RobG Yes, already duped it.

Comment: @Barmar—thanks, always takes a few minutes to find one… ;-)

Comment: @RobG It's one of my saved dupes.